# Playing musicSequence on AVAudioEngine

Tags: ios, objective-c, midi, avaudioengine

`AVAudioEngine` has a `musicSequence` property that can be set. However, I am having a hard time figuring out how to play it? I tried using `startAndReturnError` but to no avail

Answer (score 2):

This is good example how you can use it.
[MusicSequence](https://github.com/genedelisa/MusicSequence)

[AVAudioEngine](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioEngine_Class/index.html)
Also this is documentation for AudioEngine

Please look

The music sequence that was previously attached to the audio engine.

Declaration
SWIFT

```
var musicSequence: MusicSequence
```

OBJECTIVE-C

```
@property(nonatomic) MusicSequence musicSequence
```

Availability
Available in iOS 8.0 and later.